# Postgresql row count not working accurately

Tags: postgresql, count

I have a table with **2.44 million** rows, and after loading it into server:

```
copy sample_table
from 'C:\sample_table.txt'
delimiter E'\t'
csv header
```

if I do

```
select count(*) from sample_table
```

pgAdmin 4 will return count as only **1.35 million** rows

I found it odd, so I exported this table and looked at the number of rows in Notepad++, and it is still 2.44 million rows (in fact there is 1 row count difference and not sure why, but guess will worry about that later)

As recommended by Adrian in comments, I verified this in psql, and still only see 1.35M.
[image]

Any advice please? Thank you!

Comment: The one row difference would be the header row. Are you sure you are connected to the same database in pgAdmin as the database you imported the CSV into? Or is there more then one `sample_table` in the database and you dealing with versions in different schema? Have you logged in with `psql`  to do the `count(*)` to verify?

Comment: Thank you@AdrianKlaver. The table name is not sample_table - I used it here for simplicity. The real name is quite unique, which I only started to use today. Also verified in psql, please see the screenshot above.

Comment: Suspect an integrity problem in the input file. Try dumping the table, comparing it with the file to find missing rows, and examine those for a pattern. Writing CSV files that actually conform to the CSV standard is surprisingly difficult.

Comment: @Gene Thank you for your reply. I did export the table and save it to another file. This file has 2.4 M rows successfully, so I got nothing to compare to... Please let me know if I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: Hi. I'd still suspect something wrong with the input that is being undone when the table is dumped. Maybe the final column is a sometimes improperly escaped string that causes psql to gobble the next line or two as part of the column. Dumping might produce a correct-looking text file even though the number of records is wrong.  You could check for this problem by filtering the input file to get a list of primary keys. Then write a little script to seek keys with no corresponding row. The only other possibility I see is a broken psql... a bad build. That's fairly unlikely.

Comment: Are there string fields with linebreaks in the data? (Not sure how escaping works in CSV)

Comment: If there are line breaks in the input data, such as text with carriage returns, the number of rows will be different from the number of lines.

Comment: Hi @Jeremy and Bergi thank you for your comments, I opened the file in Notepad++ and searched for inconsistent line breaks but did not find any. Also searched for double and single quotes but could not find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using CSV format, literal newlines enclosed in quotes do not terminate a row.

```
"How now
Brown cow"
```

Is 2 "lines", but only 1 row.

If you re-export in the default text format, then the number of lines should match the number of rows, with the literal newlines turned into the two-character escape `\n`

Comment: Thank you @jjanes - you and many who left comments are right. The table indeed has quotes at the end of the line. Appreciate the help!